# Error Property "Content" can't be set more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I'm attempting to set up tabs in my wpf application but I keep getting this error when I try to create elements within the tab.

```
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <Label x:Name="WorkingLabe1" Content="Test1"/>
            <Label x:Name="WorkingLabelTest"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <Label x:Name="WorkingLabel2" Content="Test2"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<TabItem>` can only have one child element, so you can't have two labels inside. Instead you can place a `<Grid>` and then place two labels inside it.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="WorkingLabe1" Content="Test1"/>
            <Label x:Name="WorkingLabelTest"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <Label x:Name="WorkingLabel2" Content="Test2"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```